# Choose file in external storage and get path

Tags: kotlin, get, android-edittext, uri, filepath

i know this question has been asked several times but everything i can find is only in Java and not very relevant to me...
I'm trying to select a file when i click on a button in my app (images or videos like : /storage/emulated/0/Download/giphy.gif ) and the when the picture or video is selected, i need the path to go inside an edittext.
I have found that code in kotlin for path :

```
    class URIPathHelper {

    fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val isKitKatorAbove = true

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKatorAbove && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
                }

            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                var contentUri: Uri? = null
                if ("image" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("video" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("audio" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                }
                val selection = "_id=?"
                val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
            }
        } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
        } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return uri.path
        }
        return null
    }

    fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)
        try {
            cursor = uri?.let { context.getContentResolver().query(it, projection, selection, selectionArgs,null) }
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val column_index: Int = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(column_index)
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) cursor.close()
        }
        return null
    }

    fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
    }
}
```

And this is what i'm trying :

```
    binding.redloader.setOnClickListener {
            val uriPathHelper = URIPathHelper()
            val filePath: String? = uriPathHelper.getPath(this, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(filePath)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file"))
            binding.redgif.setText(filePath)
        }
```

When I click on the button it automatically chooses the first picture in the storage, and then it opens google picture but I cannot do anything except watch the pictures...
I'm sorry I know they are some stupid things in my code, I think I have something to do with intent but all I see on the internet is calling private void and it is not working for me...
I'm a complete beginner and I really hope someone can help me...

Update with what i'm trying, i think i'm close :

```
binding.redloader.setOnClickListener {
        val uriPathHelper = URIPathHelper()
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = "image/*"

        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)

        intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a file")
        val resultLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    val data: Intent? = result.data
                    if (data != null) {
                        val fileUri: Uri? = data.data
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, fileUri.toString())

                        var fileURIPathHelper: String? = null
                        try {
                            fileURIPathHelper = uriPathHelper.getPath(this, EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + e)
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        this.binding.redgif.setText(fileURIPathHelper)
                    }
                }
            }
            resultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it ! :)

```
val resultLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    val data: Intent? = result.data
                    if (data != null) {
                        val fileUri: Uri? = data.data
                        Log.i(PackageManagerCompat.LOG_TAG, fileUri.toString())

                        val contentUri: String?
                        try {
                            contentUri = uriPathHelper.getPath(this, fileUri!!)
                            this.binding.redgif.setText(contentUri)
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Log.e(PackageManagerCompat.LOG_TAG, "Error: " + e)
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    binding.redloader.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file"))
        resultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
```